# Inline non-numeric values defined in ambient context

Tags: typescript

`const enum` is inlined:

```
declare const enum MyEnum {
    A = 5,
    B = 7,
    D = 22
}
var x = MyEnum.A;
```

becomes the following emitted Javascript:

```
var x = 5;
```

However, enums are only number-based. Is there any mechanism that inlines values of other types (string, boolean etc.) declared in an ambient context?

**Update**

I've created [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9729) on GitHub (@basarat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any mechanism that inlines values of other types (string, boolean etc.) declared in an ambient context?

No. And you are the first one to request it (move to Microsoft/TypeScript/issues if you want). Also const enums can be a pain as well (put a hard dependency on a particular version of enums ... so you need to be careful when adding new enum members to add them at the end).

Comment: _so you need to be careful when adding new enum members to add them at the end_ -- Or explicitly specify values for the enums (which can also be done later).

Comment: yup. But with explicit values be careful not to change them. The final values might no longer be ordered which might make debugging painful. Reminds me of `BASIC` `10,20,30,...` :)

Comment: This has changed with the introduction of string enums. Do you want to update this, or should I?